# Does polr require all dependent factors to be numeric

Tags: r, ordered-logit

This is my first try at any regression and unfortunately I'm starting with an ordered logit model using the `polr` function in R. Does `polr` require all ordered factors with values like a,b,c to be converted into numbers like 1,2,3 instead of a,b,c before I use it?

Comment: Why don't you try both and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used it, but its [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/polr.html) (i.e. `?polr`) doesn't say anything about it. Also, examples provided in the documentation use `factor` type variables, so it also suggests that the answer is no. Generally, it's good to check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It does not require numeric values of predictors. In fact as a logistic regression you should feed FACTORS as predictors where it applies (they can be labeled). Otherwise ordinal as well as interval scales are accepted by polr.